# Creating a syntax checker for custom scripting language in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, scripting

My company uses a scripting language which i have not been able to find the origins of. It seems to be bits of everything.

Anyway im sick of making stupid mistakes in my code and it not being picked up until runtime.
Or more complicated issues like the accidental reuse of global and local variables without noticing which can cause unexpected results which are hard to trace.

Id like to write a syntax checker and im looking for recommendations on how to go about this. Im a C# developer so that would be my language of choice.

Anyone know of any open source similar developments which i vould modify or atleast give me some ideas about how to go about this?

Comment: you want to create your own scripting language?

Comment: Although I find your question interesting, I believe it is not appropriate to the rules of this site. See About page `Get answers to practical, detailed questions`

Comment: No my company has already created their own scripting language but they have not created a syntax checker for it. Im looking to write a syntax checker.

Comment: @CathalMF How extensively used is this scripting language? All these problems seem like a good indicator to get shot of it in favour of a mature scripting language with tool support.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth Unfortunately its very widely used and has been used within the company for atleast 15 years. It serves a very useful purpose and isnt going to go away anytime soon.

Comment: @CathalMF I'd suggest also taking this requirement back to your team in order to invest time creating tools. Compile-time checks can save time later, this is usually a good selling point to the management team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if you want a syntax checker, you go to Lex/Yacc, I think.

Another solution may be [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/), though I didn't use it by myself.

A last solution would be to do it on your own.

Comment: Irony looks very useful and at the very least it will give me some good ideas.

Comment: @CathalMF Glad it helped, you can upvote me now and if it really helped you realizing your syntax checker, then come back to validate my answer ;)